# Linux Terminal dig example -d

Tags: linux, terminal, dig

I am really having trouble making a post and this question is nowhere asked on the internet and i need to know if it is harmful so i can correct my mistake. I ran the following command in the Linux Terminal "dig example.gov -d". This started copying and deleting files as well as clearing logs.

Is this a harmful command and what does it do? I feel like it might be a diagnostic

Comment: Thanks to both of you, that was the worst mistype i could ever do when i typed (-d)! made me panic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you get are debugging (`-d`) messages. They are harmless and are used to tell what the program is doing.

Answer (score 0):

What Linux flavour do you have?
`dig` usually does DNS lookups, and the "-d" flag is probably for debugging, so it should NOT delete files/clear logs.